# MySQL starting error on CentOS 6

Tags: mysql

I have removed the preinstalled MySQL from CentOS 6 using the command-

```
yum remove mysql mysql-*
```

Now, I want to install "MySQl-server-5.5.28-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm" in my system.
But it could not start on my system. Please tell me how to start the MySQL with user account as well as in root also.

I have done this:-

```
[rex@dhcppc0 MySQL]$ 
[rex@dhcppc0 MySQL]$ su -
Password: 
[root@dhcppc0 ~]# cd /home/rex/Documents/Software/MySQL
[root@dhcppc0 MySQL]# rpm -i MySQL-server-5.5.28-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm
    package MySQL-server-5.5.28-1.linux2.6.i386 is already installed

[root@dhcppc0 MySQL]# mysql -u
-bash: mysql: command not found
[root@dhcppc0 MySQL]# mysql -u mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found
[root@dhcppc0 MySQL]# mysql.server start
-bash: mysql.server: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL-server-xxxx is package that contains only MySQL Server. Executable file for server is "mysqld" - "d" letter is for a [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29)).

**File that you trying to execute (mysql) is MySQL client. There is no client application in server package.**

Please install MySQL-client-xxxx package, where xxxx is a version.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the initscript below as a root user:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

If you try to access the database from local client, you need to install MySQL-client-5.5.28-1.linux2.6.i686.rpm package.
Then you can control the MySQL database.

```
$ /usr/bin/mysql -u mysql
```